# Highcharts sankey diagram node rearrangement

Tags: highcharts, sankey-diagram

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      width: width,
      height: height
    },
    series: [{
      keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
      data: [
        ['a', 'd', 1],
        ['b', 'c', 1],
        ['c', 'd', 1]
      ],
      type: 'sankey'
    }]
  });
});
```

When plotting two flows, a->d and b->c->d, Highcharts gives a strange node arrangement until the page is resized or the chart is reflowed:

Actual:

[image: actual]

Expected:

[image: expected]

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/applewil/ezjfarh4/6/

Why do I need to resize or reflow to get the expected arrangement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to this reported issue on Highcharts GitHub: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8218

---

As a workaround, you can call `reflow` after a chart is loaded.

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function() {
                this.reflow();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vdLy2a0z/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#reflow

Comment: Although my example is not a circular flow, the issue is still relevant. The workaround fixes it

Comment: I have tried this with a recent highcharts version and its vue.js wrapper, and it turned out that `this.reflow()` checks there whether we really had some size change, so this did not do anything. Also, listening to the `load` event seems not to be helpful when the chart is loaded off-screen. What did work for me was waiting a bit after component load or property change (`await nextTick()` in the case of vue), and then directly call `chart.setSize(0, 0, false)`.